# ORA-29280: invalid directory path using directory in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a CSV file with procedure and this file is saving in my computer, but with my code I have one error. Can you help me please?

My code is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE JSP

as

   CURSOR C_donnees IS
      select distinct CODPRO, MOTCLE,CODZN6,CODZN8
      From PRO WHERE CODZN6 = 'C' AND CODSOC = '1';
 
   w_sysdate varchar2(20);
   w_repertoire varchar2(64);
   w_fichier varchar2(80);
   l_fichier_log      utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
   -- INITIALISATION DES VARIABLES ---
   -----------------------------------
   SELECT To_Char(SysDate, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') DATEJOUR INTO w_sysdate FROM Dual;
   w_repertoire := 'C:\Users\julie\Documents\Singer Safety\Fichie SQL';
   w_fichier := 'extraction_'||w_sysdate||'.csv';
   --  ouverture du ficher ---
   dbms_output.put_line('Début de la boucle');
   l_fichier_log  := utl_file.fopen( w_repertoire, w_fichier, 'A');
   --  PARCOUR LE SELECT ---
   -------------------------------------
   FOR r_donnees IN c_donnees
   LOOP
      -- ecriture des lignes du select dans le fichier
      utl_file.put_line(l_fichier_log, r_donnees.CODPRO || ';' || r_donnees.MOTCLE    || ';' || r_donnees.CODZN6 || ';' || r_donnees.CODZN8 );
   END LOOP;
   ---------    fermeture des fichiers et fin    ----------
   UTL_FILE.fclose_all;
   dbms_output.put_line('FIN du script');
END; -- fin de la procédure
```

And I have this error:

```
ORA-29280: chemin de répertoire non valide
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_FILE", ligne 41
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_FILE", ligne 478
ORA-06512: à "C##JLECAT.JSP", ligne 21
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Code that runs in the database server cannot access your client computer directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `location` parameter to `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` must be an Oracle directory object name, not a path string. These can be created like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_dir AS '/usr/bin/my_directory';
```

Then you would specify 'MY_DIR' as the `location`, i.e.

```
w_repertoire := 'MY_DIR';
```

Also, the location has to be accessible to the database server, not local to your machine as your path appears to be.

Comment: It may be usefult to check the existing directories with this query:
select * from ALL_DIRECTORIES order by DIRECTORY_NAME;

Answer (score 2):

You're running the pl/sql in the database. utl_file will look for that directory on the database server, not on the client machine. If you want to export from sqldeveloper to your local machine, I suggest storing your data in a table and then using the sqldeveloper export functionality to save it as a csv.